# FlywayDB: Run same name SQL again

Tags: java, automation, flyway

Here is my structure, different teams are working on code base and they are checking in SQL files in database repository in which we have release wise folders and file naming convention is JIRATicket_Title_DML or DDL.sql

Then we maintain one txt file in which sequence of SQL file execution so that can maintain dependency.

Migrator pick the files in same sequence and execute manually as of now.

I started thinking automating this scenario using FlywayDB but thing is teams can update same script again with some details or correction but FlyWay don't alow same file run again and it fail showing error as checksum not matching etc.

How to implement and what will be best practice here to implement for full database CI?

Comment: Any one there to guide here :)

Comment: is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In latest release 4 it is allowed to run same SQL again.

Comment: How?  After V1__Baseline.sql, we now have a V2__newSQL.sql and did the migration which worked fine.   Now, we have a few more changes to add to this file, and I want to re-run V2 again.   How can I do this?   We can't delete the database and drop the tables, and re-baseline.

Comment: Please go through this link, it will tell how https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/repeatable